# Liberty: Custom User Registry with unresolved dependencies

Tags: websphere-liberty, osgi-bundle, ibm-wdt

Am a noob in OSGI development. Due to requirements, I had created a osgi bundle project, for a custom user registry feature in Eclipse with WDT and subsequently a feature project to export a .esa file for it.

I'm then able to install the feature into our websphere liberty, however when start it hit the error below:

```
Unresolved Requirement Require-Bundle: com.ibm.websphere.v85.core
```

The bundle require the plugin in order to build for the custom user registry. Once I have added the required plugin `com.ibm.websphere.v85.core` i can build successfully.[image: adding plugin]

I have tried to include the bundle together when i export the feature, but the same error persist.

Any advice on how to solve this dependency issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your eclipse workspace is setup, but that bundle is a WAS traditional bundle that doesn't exist in Liberty. Instead of adding Require-Bundle you should use Import-Package to import any packages you need. I would also suggest checking the plug-in development environment preferences for eclipse to make sure you have it configured with Liberty as the target platform rather than WAS traditional.

Comment: Had created the Liberty runtime and configured the project target runtime to it, however now i couldn't use `org.osgi.framework` and my `Activator` class is throwing erros for it.

Comment: After much deliberating with the Liberty OSGI runtime am able to get it to work, thanks for this answer.